# How to suppress startup messages

Tags: gnuplot, startup, app-startup

When I launch gnuplot from command line it prints 15 lines of about information I usually don't need. How can I suppress them?
Here's an example:

```
myHost: ~ gnuplot

        G N U P L O T
        Version 4.4 patchlevel 0
        last modified March 2010
        System: Linux 2.6.34.10-0.6-desktop

        Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2010
        Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

        gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
        faq, bugs, etc:   type "help seeking-assistance"
        immediate help:   type "help"
        plot window:      hit 'h'

Terminal type set to 'wxt'
gnuplot>
```

Comment: You cannot suppress this message with an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command line method to suppress the banner messages but the best thing about open source software is that you can modify it to fit your needs.

Though many (myself included) may consider this need a *strange* one, you can certainly do it. Just download the source, remove the banners (or add a command line option to be silent), recompile and run.

Alternatively, you could raise a feature request on the development site for a `--silent` command line option, and hopefully some accommodating developer will action it.

Both those possibilities should be doable from the [development page](http://www.gnuplot.info/development/).

In fact, I've even done that latter one for you [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1706/). What sort of reception it will get, I have no idea - the developers may be quite attached to the banner message. If it gets rejected, I'd suggest then going the first route, in which case the [CVS repository browser](http://gnuplot.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gnuplot/gnuplot/src/) would be a good place to start.